# Probability of a car having a defect in the brakes or fueling system?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Given the following probabilities,

defect in brakes = **0.25**

defect in transmission = **0.18**

defect in fuel = **0.17**

defect elsewhere = **0.40**

**Q.** What is the probability that the defect is in the brakes or in the fuel system if the probability of both having a brake and fuel defect is 0.15?

**Here is my following work/interpretation of the question:**

Let B = defective brakes

Let F = defective fuel

Hence we have the following formula:

**Pr(B union F) = Pr(B) + Pr(F) - Pr(B intersection F)**

plugging in the numbers and solving the formula we have

**Pr(B union F) = 0.25 + 0.17 - 0.15 = 0.27**

**Q.** What is the probability of there being no defects in either the brakes or fuel?

I believe the answer is:

**1-0.27 = 0.73**

If I have done something wrong, please if possible explain to me the error that I made. Thank you for looking over my question and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ad Q2:**

It is $P(\overline A \cup \overline B)=1-P(A \cap B)$

I replaced F by A.

In a Venn-diagram you can color the events $\overline A$ and $\overline B$. The only remaining uncolored area is the intersection of area F and area B.

First you color the area $\overline A$ blue.

[image]

Then you color the  area $\overline B$ yellow. The area, which is now green, is the area, which is colored blue and yellow. The white area hasn´t been colored.

[image]